# Materialize scrollspy offset issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

So to begin with here is the issue:

[image]

The red line should be on `topicTimer0` not offset above it. The menu is setup at the top of the body with the following code (notably this is not what the original html looks like but rather after elements have been added with jquery):

```
<div class="col s2 z-depth-2">
    <h3>timer</h3>
    <hr>
    <ul class="section table-of-contents">
        <li><a href="#topic0OnScreen" class="active"><h5>topicTimer0</h5></a>
            <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#topic1OnScreen" class=""><h5>topicTimer1</h5></a>
            <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#topic2OnScreen" class=""><h5>topicTimer2</h5></a>
            <ul></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is what the original html looks like:

```
<div class="col s2 z-depth-2">
    <h3>timer</h3>
    <hr>
    <ul class="section table-of-contents">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle of it in this state:(https://jsfiddle.net/u1owwv9p/) now it should be noted on JSFIddle it adds some extra issues like adding a new `topicTimer` to the list and adding another topic header at the bottom, but these issues do not appear in the actual program, the only one that does is the one I have illustrated.

In case it's desired here is a link to the documentation for what I'm doing here:(http://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html).

Comment: The amount attached to the fiddle (along with endless repetition) makes it quite hard to troubleshoot. Can you be a bit more specific on what the exact context of your issue is and what steps have you taken/tried towards fixing the problem?

Comment: @MattNewelski Yeah I understand, it's a very hard issue to show properly and tbh I know the question is not done great, I will continue to improve bits of it if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strictly [css](/questions/tagged/css) question. In order for these two elements to be centered in relation to each other they need to have the same height:

[image: Difference between <a> element's and <h5> element's rendering]

Setting the `height` of the `<a>` element to match that of the `<h5>` element is one solution *[materialize.min.css:13]*:

```
.table-of-contents a {
   height: 110%
}
```

I would suggest manipulating the `height`, `line-height` and `font-size` values of both the `<a>` and `<h5>` elements to better understand their dependencies and hopefully find the setting that best fits your needs.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but what does '[materialize.min.css:13]' mean?

Comment: It is not a dumb question if you are not familiar with this format. This means that the class declaration mentioned is on line _13_ of the _materialize.min.css file_.